# How to pass keyword in python lambda function?

Tags: python

Can we use pass keyword inside python lambda function or can I use only "If" condition without else in python lambda function?

I have tried:

```
f=lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0 else pass
```

and

```
f=lambda x: True if x % 2 == 0
```

Comment: you have to return something either way. So just do `f=lambda x: x % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to return something anyway, why not just return the evaluated Boolean result.

```
>>> f=lambda x: x % 2 == 0
>>> f(2)
True
>>> f(3)
False
>>>
```

If you are adamant about not returing anything for `False` case, you can do it in such a way:

```
>>> f=lambda x: x % 2 == 0 or None
>>> f(2)
True
>>> f(3)
>>>
```

Comment: I would have done `lambda x: x % 2 == 0 or None`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre point taken!

Answer (score 0):

No, but you don't need to. You don't need `if` at all, because your condition by itself evaluates to a boolean. Just do:

```
f = lambda x: x % 2 == 0
```